# Join a group of python processes with a timeout

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using python's multiprocessing library to create several processes.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
processes = [Process(target=function) for function in FUNCTIONS]
for p in processes:
    p.start()
```

I want them to run for some duration and then if they have not completed, terminate them.

```
DURATION = 3600
```

A bad way to do it is as follows (bad because if the processes finish faster than DURATION, it still waits for all of DURATION):

```
from time import sleep
sleep(duration)
for p in processes:
    p.join(0)
    p.terminate()
```

Another bad way to do it (bad because it can possibly take N * DURATION to finish, where N is the number of processes):

```
for p in processes:
    p.join(DURATION)
    p.terminate()
```

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: I don't know what your processes are doing but normally you would use a signalling variable to signal to the process it's time to finish. So you would way DURATION, set the var and wait to join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this does what you want without any polling required, and it will only wait up to your specified DURATION.

```
time_waited = 0
then = time.time()
for p in processes:
    if time_waited >= DURATION:
        p.join(0)
        p.terminate()
    p.join(DURATION - time_waited)
    time_waited = time.time() - then
```

Comment: Why do you update `then`?  You can just have `time_waited = now - then` instead of the last two lines.

Comment: Hmm yea that'd work fine too. I guess for some reason the way I have it was what naturally came to me first. Maybe your way is a bit clearer though. I'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

This will poll every second for whether all of the processes are completed, up to DURATION.  If either all processes have finished or DURATION has occurred, it joins/kills all of the processes.  It's not perfect, in that it will take slightly longer than a second in each iteration of the for loop, but it will be pretty close.

```
from time import sleep
for _ in range(DURATION):
    if not any(i.is_alive() for i in processes): break
    sleep(1)
for p in processes:
    p.join(0)
    p.terminate()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is probably to have a "master" thread which `join(0)`s all the processes and then exits, and have the main thread `join(3600)` the master thread.

```
def wait_func():
    for p in processes:
    p.join()

wait_process = Process(target=wait_func)
wait_process.start()
wait_process.join(DURATION)
for p in processes:
    p.terminate()
```